# Detecting from which USB port input comes

Tags: java, usb, raspberry-pi2

I have a project in which input would come from multiple peripherals (in this case, barcode scanners) and I would need to know which barcode scanner the input is coming from, but all I have found when researching this was comminicating with USB drive. I am using Java on a Raspberry Pi 2.

Comment: Litle bit less information you provide but I think you use hidapi. If so look in this class: HIDDeviceInfo there is a property interface_number which should be what your are looking for.

Comment: otherwise try to get result of lsusb

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your application will do specific things with data from specific bar-code scanners i.e. scanner1 is connected to cash register 1 and scanner2 to register 2 etc. Further I assume that you use some standard scanner hardware which identifies to a Linux system as an HID *keyboard* device.

On modern Linux operating systems such as Raspbian USB devices are registered as device nodes in `/dev/input/by-id`. An example of a keyboard connected to my Pi is: `/dev/input/by-id/usb-0130_0005-event-kbd`.

Linux HID device nodes allow you to directly read from them just like you would read from a file. This means that you can do something like the following, to make sure that your Java program reads from a particular barcode scanner only:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(
        new FileInputStream("/dev/input/by-id/usb-0130_0005-event-kbd"));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    // evaluate the EAN code which is now in line
}
```

Assumption that your scanner like ours send a carriage return / line feed after each successfully scanned code.

We use similar code in one of our applications to make sure, that our users not accidentally scan EAN codes in other fields such as names and description fields. In our application bar code scanners add items to an item list and keyboard input is exclusively used for other user input.

On application startup in the `main` method we use code similar to this in order to make sure that keyboard and barcode scanners get distinguished.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String keyboardInput = args[0];
    String barcodeInput = args[1];
    // see code above how to read from the particular devices
}
```

As for application startup we use Linux command line tools to determine which device nodes refer to the barcode scanner and which to the keyboard. Basically a combination of `lsusb` and a set of Udev rules that get executed whenever a USB device is connected to the machine. However, this is out of the context of your question.